# CSV How to delete row depending of user choice

Tags: ruby, csv, model-view-controller, delete-file

Hi I got a program where the user can write a gossip, with an author and a content. And I save this in a CSV file. Like this :

```
author1,content1
author2,content2
author3,content3
```

And I want to ask at the user which line he want to delete with a simple gets.to_i. Then if the user enter `2` that gonna delete the 2nd row. If he enter `3` the 3rd ect...
How can i delete i line depending of the user choice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this if that can help someone :

```
def self.delete(index_to_delete)
    gossips = Gossip.all # Creation tempory array
    gossips.delete_at(index_to_delete - 1) # delete the choosen row
    File.open("db/gossip.csv", "w") do |f|
        f << ""         # clean csv file
    end
    gossips.map { |g| g.save } # save the new array as csv (with an other def to save)
end
```

I 'm sure that was not the best way but that worked !

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CSV::Table#delete`

```
i = gets.to_i
table = CSV.table(file).by_row

table.delete(i)
```

Comment: I've try this and I try to modifiate you answer but that not worked, anyone got another idea ?